# HighCharts: How to display xAxis between a DateTime range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, highcharts

I am using a line chart with the 'datetime' xAxis. I have `pointStart: 'April 08, 2015 07:00 PM'` and `tickAmount: 12` for a 12 hour display. The graph shows April 8 on the xAxis, but displays 12am to 12pm instead of the 7am to 7pm.

Here is my configuration:

```
x_axis_start_time = 'April 08, 2015 07:00 PM -700'.to_datetime

@pv_chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.chart({:zoomType =>'x'})

    f.options[{
      useUTC: false,
      scrollbar: { enabled: true }
      }]

    f.title({ :text=>"PV Module Temperature"})

    f.xAxis [
      {
        type: 'datetime',
        pointStart: x_axis_start_time,
        pointInterval:  1 * 3600 * 1000,
        tickAmount: 12,
        tickInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
      }
    ]

    f.yAxis [
      {
        title: {text: "Temperature ( °C )",
                margin: 30},
      }
    ]

    f.legend(:align => 'center', :verticalAlign => 'bottom', :layout => 'horizontal')

    f.series( :name=> 'PV1', :data=> @avg_pv1, color: '#FF6138', \
      pointStart: x_axis_start_time, pointInterval: 60 )

    f.series( :name=> 'PV2', :data=> @avg_pv2, color: '#00A388', \
      pointStart: x_axis_start_time, pointInterval: 60 )

  end
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DinTq.png

I read on another SO thread that passing in UNIX epoch or milliseconds works, but when I convert the DateTime object to int and * 1000, the graph does not display. How can I start xAxis labels from a particular hour?

**EDIT**:

```
start_time = '2015-04-02 07:00:00 -0700'.to_time
end_time = '2015-04-02 19:00:00 -0700'.to_time

f.xAxis [{
  type: 'datetime',
  pointStart: start_time,
}]

f.series( :name=> 'PV1', :data=> @avg_pv1, color: '#FF6138', \
    pointInterval: min_inter * 60, pointStart: start_time, \
    tickInterval: 1 * 3600, tickAmount: 12,  \
    min: start_time, max: end_time)
```

This configuration works the way I want the points to display, but the xAxis is not using pointStart: start_time. It uses the date though.

Comment: Try to use highstock and then set [oridinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) as false.

Comment: I was able to get the data points configured, but the time in pointStart value is not being used. I have pointStart: 'April 8, 2015 7:00' as a Time object, but the xAxis still displays from midnight to 12 noon.

Comment: In highstock as well? Could you paste your data as json here?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was able to solve my problem a different way. I created an array of timestamps from the records and displayed them along the X-axis.